# Как запустить анимацию объекта в Unity при клике на кнопку используя C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Сегодня начал осваивать компонент *Animation* в Unity2D, сделал анимацию появления стартового окна, но вот дальше у меня начали появляться проблемы с пониманием. Я хочу сделать анимацию открытия окна магазина, ну понятное дело, что она должна запускаться при нажатии на кнопку *Магазин*, только вот проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как это сделать. Метод открытия панели магазина в одном коде, а сама анимация в другом, чтобы не сваливать все в одну кучу. Я активировал стартовую анимацию через GetComponent, но для этого нужно, чтобы скрипт весел на объекте, который содержит в себе этот компонент. Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ активировать анимацию?

Код с анимацией

```
private void Awake()
{
   GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Welcome");
   GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PointsPanel");
   GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Close");
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого сделай скрипт на любом объекте, скажем, MenuManager. И в методе Start() получи компонент анимации, и также в нём сделай собственный метод, который будет запускать анимацию, используя компонент анимации. Далее в настройках кнопки выбери настройку OnClick, нажми на + и укажи там объект, у которого есть вышеуказанный скрипт, и далее выбери тот самый скрипт и запусти там собственный метод, готово.

Comment: спасибо, Вам, большое!)